# GAMA agent based modeling 1.5.1 issue with Eclipse Indigo sr2 and PDE plugin "unable to open editor" message

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am using the GAMA framework for agent based modeling, which relies on Eclipse Indigo SR2. I was not sure if this was a GAMA issue or an Eclipse issue, so I am posting to both the GAMA help as well as Stackoverflow.

So I am using Eclipse Indigo Modeling Framework and I cannot seem to load the .product file for the Plugin. Whenever I try and load it, it just shows "unable to open editor" in the Product Configuration Editor window. There is really no message or error indicated, so I am not sure how to debug this one. I thought I might be missing a plugin, but it seems that the GAMA svn project will download all of the plugins necessary. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have included a picture to demonstrate the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out. In this case, you need to click on the Java perspective before it will work. So the omission was simply changing the perspective. Good lesson though.